# SQL - How to count a value and add it back to a column within a query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following data from fruits table:

```
Fruits | Qty.
Grapes |  5
Apple  |  3
Oranges|  2
Bananas|  1  
Kiwi   |  1
```

I want to group all fruits that have a qty. <= 2. The desired result should look this:

```
Fruits | Qty.
Grapes |  5
Apple  |  3
Other  |  4
```

What is the query in SQL to get the desired result?

I tried using a CASE statement to tag the rows then use COUNT to count the group but I don't understand how to add back the result of the count of 'other' back to the table I am querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve that:

```
SELECT Fruits, Qty FROM fruits WHERE Qty > 2
UNION ALL
SELECT "Other", SUM(Qty) from fruits where Qty <= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Does sqlite allow a group by 1? If so, this works too...

```
    select 
    case
        when qty > 2 then fruits
        else 'Other'
    end fruits, 
    sum(qty) as qty
    from fruits
    group by 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes sqlite allows GROUP BY. However when I tried your code the result ended up creating a column called fruits_1 that categorized the fruits based on their quantity (qty) :/